# Gravity forms table select records with field number x.x

Tags: sql, forms, gravity

I am running into a problem I cannot get my head around. I have a gravity forms form with some questions that use check boxes. In the table the field_numbers per answer have a digit. So question 24 has three answers which correspond in the table to:
_________field_value
answer 1 : 24.1
answer 2 : 24.2
answer 3 : 24.3

If I want to select all records with 24.1 (or any other field_number with a .x) I get an empty result. All other questions with other types (radio-buttons, etc.) I can select on via an sql query. However the questions with checkboxes I cannot select on.

Does anybody have an answer to this question?

Tnx in advance,

Michel

Comment: what is the underlying database?

Comment: tnx for your reply...it is a mysql database

Comment: by the way.. it does give a return with .5 decimals. however not with .1, .2, .3, .4, .6, .7, .8, .9